# Build ExtJS tree on fly

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, tree

I am beginner in ExtJS programming, and I looking for the best approach to implement the following:

I need to build ExtJs tree dynamically, on fly by dragging and dropping available nodes and leaves to the treepanel.

Please suggest anything, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See 'ExtJS in Action' by Jesus Garcia. Chapter 14.4 has all the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you may want to check out Saki's website below - it has some good code examples. Look at the "Drag and Drop" section where he has a tree and grid example.

http://examples.extjs.eu/